# Java socket read timeout exceptions

Tags: java, sockets, client-server, inputstream

I try to overcome a user disconnection detection on the server side using read timeout.
This is part of my code:

```
try {
        socket.setSoTimeout(3000);
        in = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
        out = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        usr = new User(in.readUTF());
        usr.connectUser();
        int i=0;
        while(true){
            try{
                i = in.readInt();
            }
            catch(SocketTimeoutException e){
                System.Out.Println("Timeout");
                // user connected, no data received
            }
            catch(EOFException e){
                System.Out.Println("Disconnected");
                // user disconnected
            }
        }
    }
    catch(Exception  e){
        // other exceptions
    }
```

the code works fine except the "user disconnected" issue.
i want to catch the timeout exception and just continue waiting for data
but only if the client still connected.
why i never get other exception than SocketTimeoutException?
shouldn't i get IOException while in.readInt() can't use the socket because client disconnected?

is there any other simple way to detect user disconnection?
i mean as unwanted disconnection, like user had suddenly wifi shutdown etc...

thanks,
Lioz.

Answer (score 0):

If the client didn't write anything within the timeout period, you get a SocketTimeoutException. If he disconnected instead of writing anything, you get an EOFException. Catch them separately. If you didn't get an EOFException, he didn't disconnect.

Comment: well... that's what i thought... the only exception i get is the timeout. i put 2 println to check it out. and i'm sure the client disconnected... my client is android cell phone, i closed it's wifi connection to be sure. any other ideas?

Comment: additional info, if i close the socket from the client side, i get the right exception... (i added the println tests to the code)

Comment: @HFDO5 The peer has to call close() for an EOS to be received by this code. Just turning things off or pulling cables doesn't do that. That's one reason timeout exceptions exist.

Comment: sure, but if there's read call and there's no connection, i should get other Exception than timeout. as i think...

Comment: @HFDO5 You can think what you like, but the actual situation is as I have stated above.

Comment: any other ideas to solve this thing? i want server that will wait always for input and can detect user disconnection. i thought if the user disconnected, the read command will timeout and in the next loop it will detect the disconnection with different exception... @EJP

Comment: @HFDO5 Thinking so doesn't make it so, any more than wishing does. In TCP, the only reliable way to detect a broken connection is to try to *write* to it.